# How do I display spans next to each other?

Tags: html, css

So my problem is that I can't place the two spans side by side, I have tried everything I could find but nothing fixed it. The idea would be that I have a CSS animation for the "buttons", but they are located on top of each other. I've tried replacing every display with `inline-block` but nothing happened.

Here is the code:

```css
.main {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#box {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  /* color: white; */
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  line-height: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .35s;
}

a span {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="gradient-border" id="box">
    <h2>'head'</h2><br>
    <h2>'text1'</h2><br>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="pages/login.php"><span style="col-lg-1">'login'</span></a>
      <a href="pages/register.php"><span style="col-lg-1">'register'</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any spans that are siblings which elements are you wanting side by side?

Comment: FYI I removed the PHP tags (they are not usable in a snippet) + I commented out the `white` color which made the text disappear. Please always make sure that things that need to be visible ARE visible.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `style="col-lg-1"` because that seems to refer to an external library which you did not mention.

I also removed the `relative` positioning and all the `inline` and `inline-block` references, since spans and anchors are already inline elements.

In short, you don't have to do anything to make spans appear next to each other.

```css
  

.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

a span {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="gradient-border" id="box">
    <h2>
      Hello World
    </h2>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="pages/login.php"><span>Login</span></a>
      <a href="pages/register.php"><span>Register</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `col-lg-1` looks like it came from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options), which could make it relevant to the problem that OP is experiencing. At the same time they could be using it all wrong, but I lack experience with Bootstrap to say for sure if they are.